# Correct way of implementing placement new in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I have implemented the placement new like this:

```
inline void* operator new (std::size_t n, void* ptr) {return ptr;};
```

The environment I use has no standard library so I need placement new. The syntax for using this placement new operator should look like this:

```
::new (pointer) int();
```

For what reason do I need the size? My std::size_t is unsigned int. The reason why I do this is because there is no dynamic memory allocation available and I get all the pointers from a pool.

Comment: Because the standard says that's how the function should look.

Comment: Because the C++ standard requires that all overloads of `operator new()` or `operator new []()` accept a `std::size_t` as the first argument (and will be passed the size of whatever is being constructed).   A placement new is simply an overload of the corresponding `operator new()` or `operator new []()`.   The reasoning is, presumably, to allow for the possibility of any such function needing to allocate memory, in which case they need to know the size.    There is nothing stopping your overloaded version from ignoring the size argument.

Comment: @Peter That looks like a good answer.

Comment: `inline void* operator new (std::size_t n, void* ptr) {return ptr;};` Is the implementation of my new operator. The compiler gives me an error: error: ‘operator new’ takes type ‘size_t’ (‘unsigned int’) as first parameter [-fpermissive].

Comment: @Gustavo - I find your setup odd. You say you don't have the header `<new>` (odd, since it's a minimum requirement from a free-standing environment that adheres to the standard), but you have `<cstddef>` and can use `std::size_t`?

Comment: No I made my own std::size_t which is an unsigned int. There is no stl available so I make my own with the basic functions I need.

Comment: The standard also says that placement form of operator new(size_t,void*) is not replaceable, maybe you should declare an overload, for exemple operator new(size_t,void*,my_type) and use this expression :`new (ptr,my_type{}) int()`. If you don't do that and link your code with other code that may produce surprises.

Comment: Ok I got one solution. Using gcc and std::size_t inside the operator overload results in an error. Defining a size_t which is not inside std namespace and using that as first parameter type compiles fine.

Comment: The documentation for placement new says std::size_t is needed but gcc (higher than 4.9) does not accept std::size_t without permissove flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I intended this to be only a comment, but following melpomene's suggestion that it is an answer ....

The C++ standard requires that all overloads of `operator new()` or `operator new []()` accept a `std::size_t` as the first argument (and that the implementation will ensure the size of whatever is being constructed is passed via that argument).

A placement new is simply an overload of the corresponding `operator new()` or `operator new []()`.   As such, it is required to be in that form.

The reasoning is, presumably, to allow for the possibility of any such overloaded function needing to allocate memory, in which case it would need access to size information.

There is nothing stopping your overloaded version from ignoring the size argument - which probably explains why the standard does not bother to allow overloading `operator new()` or `operator new[]()` without that parameter.